# How to implement or mimic https with Homebrew Apache?

Tags: security, homebrew, apache

So, I'm working on trying to develop a site using the location API and modern browsers either require you to make settings modifications, or to run the geolocation requests through https. I was wondering if there's a way of mimicing https locally, that would avoid installing let's encrypt? I don't want to manage tons of certificates locally if not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, digging around tutorials, I learned about Make Cert, which you install with Brew like this: `brew install mkcert nss`. The NSS package is so it plays nicely with Firefox.